# Error Message: "Could not clone passed arguments [[object HTMLHeadElement]]"

Tags: javascript, html, dom, error-handling

I would like to display the `<head>` element as an object in HTML DOM in JavaScript in the console in order to see the "tree"-pattern of the object. But if I do so, the message I get is:

> Could not clone passed arguments `[[object HTMLHeadElement]]` on line 1

I tried to use `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Could not clone passed arguments [[object HTMLHeadElement]] on line 1" suggests that the browser's console is having trouble directly displaying the DOM element as an object. This could be due to the complexities involved in cloning and displaying DOM elements.

However, there are other ways of inspecting the DOM element as an object in the console:

#### Using `console.dir()`

The `console.dir()` method allows you to display an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object. This method provides a way to view the properties of DOM objects.

```js
console.dir(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]);
```

#### Using JSON.stringify with a Replacer Function

You can use `JSON.stringify()` with a replacer function to convert the DOM object to a JSON string. However, this will only include enumerable properties and will lose all methods and DOM-specific behaviors.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0], (key, value) => {
  if (value instanceof Node) return 'Node';
  if (value instanceof Window) return 'Window';
  return value;
}, 2));
```

#### Using Object.assign

You can create a shallow copy of the object with `Object.assign()`. This will only include the object's own enumerable properties.

```js
console.log(Object.assign({}, document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]));
```

Each of these methods has its own limitations, but they can give you a "tree"-like view of the object's properties in the console.